# Adding a scrollbar to a composite layout does not work in java swt

Tags: java, swt

My problem is that I want to add a `Scrollbar` to a composite.

Basically I have a composite with a button. When you press the button new Content will be added to the composite (A label and a text). After some time the content overflows the composite. I want to add a scrollbar so you can see all text when adding them.

I already tried `ScrolledComposite` but somehow it won't scroll I think because it does not recognize that the content of the composite exceeds

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Slider;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowData;
import swing2swt.layout.BoxLayout;


public class test {
protected static String _intentId;
static Text intentNameText;
static Text utterance;
static Text pattern;
static int increaser=0;
static int counterNumb=1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell( display );
shell.setSize(602,474);
Composite container = new Composite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FILL);
container.setBounds(21, 10, 553, 407);          
Label lblCreateAnIntent = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
lblCreateAnIntent.setBounds(36, 30, 193, 20);
lblCreateAnIntent.setText("Create an Intent");

final Composite innerComposite = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
innerComposite.setBounds(59, 54, 475, 319);;
//innerComposite.layout();

Label lblIntentName = new Label(innerComposite, SWT.NONE);
lblIntentName.setBounds(10, 23, 97, 20);
lblIntentName.setText("Intent Name:");

intentNameText = new Text(innerComposite, SWT.BORDER);
intentNameText.setBounds(113, 23, 78, 26);

Label lblUtterances = new Label(innerComposite, SWT.NONE);
lblUtterances.setText("Utterances");
lblUtterances.setBounds(41, 83, 120, 20);

Label lblPattern = new Label(innerComposite, SWT.NONE);
lblPattern.setText("Pattern");
lblPattern.setBounds(220, 84, 120, 20);

utterance = new Text(innerComposite, SWT.BORDER);
utterance.setBounds(41, 109, 150, 26);

pattern = new Text(innerComposite, SWT.BORDER);
pattern.setBounds(220, 110, 150, 26);

final Button btnNewButton = new Button(innerComposite, SWT.NONE);
btnNewButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        increaser=increaser+40;

        Label number0 = new Label(innerComposite, SWT.NONE);
        number0.setText(Integer.toString(counterNumb));
        number0.setBounds(20, 112, 15, 20); 

        counterNumb=counterNumb+1;

        Label number = new Label(innerComposite, SWT.NONE);
        number.setText(Integer.toString(0+counterNumb) + ".");
        number.setBounds(20, 112+increaser, 15, 20);        

        utterance = new Text(innerComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        utterance.setBounds(41, 109+increaser, 150, 26);

        pattern = new Text(innerComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        pattern.setBounds(220, 110+increaser, 150, 26);
    btnNewButton.setBounds(41, 150+increaser, 121, 30);
    }
});
btnNewButton.setBounds(41, 150, 121, 30);
btnNewButton.setText("Add Utterance");




        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
}   
}
```

My Goal is that a scrollbar can be seen when the content exceeds the composite. After Scrolling whole content should be seen

Comment: `Composite` does not support scroll bars - you must use `ScrolledComposite`

Comment: You should rewrite your class to use layouts instead of fixed positioning, see https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you greg and loris for the answer, i now managed to add a scrolled composite and therefore i also used a gridlayout like loris said and changed my structure. It almost works but now i got a small bug which i cannot fix yet.

Whenever i press the button it won't directly add a new row of content. It only adds it when I resize the whole application window.

The scrollbars are working correctly as i want it, but like I said it only adds the content when resizing shell, but I want it to add it automatically. How could I do this.

Here is the new code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;

/**
 * Shows an expanding ScrolledComposite that scrolls only vertically.
 */
public class vertform {



  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    new vertform().run();
  }

  private Shell shell;
  private ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite;
  private Text text_1;
 private Composite result;  

  void run() {
    createControls();
    layoutControls();
    openShell();
    runEventLoop();
  }

  private void createControls() {
    shell = new Shell( new Display() );
    shell.setSize(577, 391);
    shell.setText( "Contact Details Form" );
    shell.addListener( SWT.Dispose, event -> event.display.dispose() );

    Label lblIntentName = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    lblIntentName.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    lblIntentName.setText("some text");

    text_1 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    GridData gd_composite = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, false, false, 1, 1);
    gd_composite.heightHint = 52;
    gd_composite.widthHint = 448;
    composite.setLayoutData(gd_composite);

    Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 34, 70, 20);
    lblNewLabel_1.setText("some Text x");

    Label lblPattern = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    lblPattern.setText("some text y");
    lblPattern.setBounds(231, 34, 70, 20);
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite( shell, SWT.V_SCROLL );
    Composite parent = createForm();
    scrolledComposite.setContent( parent );
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical( true );
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal( true );
    scrolledComposite.addListener( SWT.Resize, 
            event -> {
      int width = scrolledComposite.getClientArea().width;
      scrolledComposite.setMinSize( parent.computeSize( width, SWT.DEFAULT ) );
    } );
  }

  private void layoutControls() {
    shell.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, false ) );
    GridData gridData = new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true );
    gridData.heightHint = computePreferredHeight();
    scrolledComposite.setLayoutData( gridData );
  }

  private void openShell() {
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
  }

  private void runEventLoop() {
    while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
      if( !shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch() ) {
        shell.getDisplay().sleep();
      }
    }
  }

  private int computePreferredHeight() {
    int numberOfLines = 1;
    int defaultHorizontalSpacing = 5;
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    Button btnNewButton = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnNewButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            createField(result);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setText("Add content");
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    Text text = new Text( shell, SWT.BORDER );
    GridData gd_text = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.BOTTOM, false, false, 1, 1);
    gd_text.heightHint = 138;
    gd_text.widthHint = 587;
    text.setLayoutData(gd_text);
    text.setText( "X" );
    Point preferredSize = text.computeSize( SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT );
    text.dispose();
    return numberOfLines * ( preferredSize.y + defaultHorizontalSpacing );
  }

  private Composite createForm() {
      result=new Composite( scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE );
    result.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, false ) );
    createField( result);

    return result;
  }

  private static void createField( Composite parent) {
    Text text1=new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    Text text = new Text( parent, SWT.BORDER );
    GridData gd_text = new GridData( SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false );
    gd_text.widthHint = 208;
    text.setLayoutData( gd_text );
    GridData gd_text1 = new GridData( SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false );
    gd_text1.widthHint = 203;
    text1.setLayoutData( gd_text1 );
  }
}
```

Comment: When you add the new controls, call [`requestLayout()`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#requestLayout()) on them to reposition them and make them appear.
At the same time, to inform the `ScrolledComposite` of the change, call `setMinSize` on it.